# Managing 2 websites from 1 admin panel

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, admin

Is it possible to control 2 different Drupal website from 1 admin panel? 2 different domain, but on same host-server.

one of my client came up with the idea and I wasn't sure if it can be done.

Appreciate advices! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With http://drupal.org/project/domain you can **simulate** two websites. Is not actually two different Drupal installation.

You can take a look http://drupal.org/node/346385 for more information about the different multi-site options.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to have two domains point to the same Drupal installation (e.g. `http://example.com/` and `http://example2.com` point to the same *Example Drupal* website), this is supported out of the box as long as you don't use a multisite setup.

That is, normally, you'd just stick your `settings.php` file in `sites/default/`. If you did that, any domain that's pointed to the Drupal directory will use the same Drupal site. You don't need to do anything else.

If you've stuck your site in `sites/example.com`, you could create a symbolic link with the name of the other domain; i.e. you'd have `sites/example.com` and a symbolic link to it called `sites/example2.com`.

If you're trying to run two disparate sites through the same admin panel, you can't do it *per se*: that is, you can't manage most aspects of Drupal through its default administration system because it's not designed to do that.

However, if you're trying to simulate something like Plesk or Cpanel—that is, you just want to easily manage Drupal deployments using one control panel—there is a project under heavy development called [Aegir](http://groups.drupal.org/aegir-hosting-system). I've used it on a few different occasions and it works pretty great, but it's a somewhat involved setup process.

Answer (score 0):

No, not that I am aware. As well as the content, all the administration aspects of the site are stored in the site's database, so the admin area and the front end of the site are joined at the hip! 1 database per site, so 1 admin area per site.

Answer (score 0):

There is Aegir http://www.aegirproject.org which is a multi-site manager dashboard system.  It's more for creating and managing the site than for managing content, but it might be what you're looking for.